# How to reduce nested subscription (callback hell) in API design?

Tags: system.reactive, reactive-programming, rx-java, observable

My goal is to get A from Service, and then get B from A and Service. Also the service needs to be closed after I am done with B or exception occurs.

I come up with the following API:

```
Observable<Service> getService();
Observable<Integer> getA(Service service);
Observable<Integer> getB(Integer a, Service service)
```

And I can use it in the following:

```
getService().subscribe(s -> {
        getA(s).subscribe(a -> {
            getB(a, s).subscribe(b -> {
                doSomethingWith(b);
                s.close();
            }, r -> s.close());
        }, r->s.close());
    });
```

There are 3 levels of the nested subscription and the statement to close the service appears in all 3 subscribe().

Is there any way to reduce the number subscription (callback) and make the code easier to read and understand?

Thanks!

Comment: Use `flatMap`, `using` and ideally redesign your service so that it has `getA()` and `getB(a)` methods on it.

Answer (score 4):

`Observable.using` is what you should use to safely close the resource (including on a early unsubscription).

To avoid the nested callback problem you talk about just look to limit yourself to one `subscribe` call and use appropriate operators like `flatMap`. This way exceptions or cancels will affect the whole stream not just a segment and you can leverage other efficiences built in to Rx operators.

Assuming a slight change where the `getRawService` call returns a service rather than a stream I would rewrite your code as:

```
Observable
  .using(
    () -> getRawService(),
    s ->  
      s.getA()
       .flatMap(a -> s.getB(a))
       .doOnNext(b -> doSomethingWith(b)),
    s -> s.close())
  .subscribe(subscriber);
```

The `subscriber` above would report errors as you preferred but that's about it.

The `using` approach could be incorporated into your `getService` call so that it returned this:

```
Observable.using(
  () -> getRawService(), 
  s -> Observable.just(s),
  s -> s.close());
```

From there on you don't have to worry about closing the service so it would be:

```
getService()
  .map(s -> s.getA())
  .flatMap(a -> s.getB(a))
  .doOnNext(b -> doSomethingWith(b))
```

This usage is one of the great beauties of the RxJava approach (being able to encapsulate emission, exception and resource closure handling) and reuse it concisely, tersely.